ApexCharts Radar Chart have chart go to max data possible always
Seems with apex charts that the chart produced for radar its always to your data you have specified.
Does anyone know if its possible to have it go out to what the max value can be always instead of it going out to just the max data value you have in the series?
Edit based on kikon respone based off his fiddle this should be working:
Here is my chartOptions:
yaxis: {
  stepSize: 1,
  max: 10,
},



Can you give us more context please, at least some screen of the actual result, and the expected one

The same as with other chart types, you can set options.yAxis.max, see fiddle. If it's larger than the actual data max, it's OK, if it's smaller it won't look nice.

@kikon see my edit above I added yAxis did what you said my data points go up to 9 and can see graph goes to 9 still.
Note I am using angular.

Maybe this is a bug in https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts ? hmmm

It probably interferes with something else you're having in the code. You should try to add to the fiddle code as much as possible of your configuration object  and some data and see if you can reproduce your problem in vanilla JS, and if so share that code with us. You can also share a minimal reproducible example with Angular code in a stackblitz or codesandbox.

Ah!!! I got it... I was forgetting to bind to that... makes since cause I did try adding the yaxis min before and thought it didnt work so tried other stuff but was just forgetting to bind in my template bleh stupid!
Thanks for the help @kikon

I was not binding in the HTML properly forgot to add:
[yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis!"

To the apx-chart element.
Thanks @kikon for the hints for this and leading me here with that fiddle!
